# Multiple Qt profile directories

Tags: qt

Is there any way to change the Qt 5 profile directory in Linux (with both installed versions Qt: for desktop and android)? The second version tries to overwrite the config files with a `permission denied` message. I wish to have two different configs for both versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use [`qtchooser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/qtchooser.1.html). I have highlighted the relevant information in the description taken from man page of qtchooser, below:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Qt is a cross-platform C++ application framework. Qt's primary 
>   feature is its rich set of widgets that provide standard GUI
>   functionality.
>
> *The  Qt  Chooser  provides  a  wrapper to switch between versions of*
>   *Qt development binaries when multiple versions like 4 and 5 are* 
>   *installed or local Qt builds are to be used.*
>
> It is commonly used via a symlink from an executable_name like qmake.

The answer to the question [Qt5 installation and path configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435564/qt5-installation-and-path-configuration) should help you.

> Replace Default Qt version paths in
>   `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/default.conf`:
>
> ```
> /opt/Qt5/bin
> /opt/Qt5/lib
> ```
>
> Check:
>
> ```
> qtchooser -print-env
> ```
>
> Reference: [`man qtchooser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/qtchooser.1.html)